# Open Messagebox when JTable cell double-clicked

Tags: java, swing, jtable, awt, joptionpane

When I double click a cell in a specific cell in my JTable, I'd like a JOptionPane message box to pop up dislaying the text that's currently contained in the cell. I know I'll need to use `.getColumnModel().getCOlumn(3).setCellEditor(new x());` but I don't know if theres already a construct I can use as x to do what I need, or if I'll need to make a new class. I'm also not too sure how I'll need to lay that out if that's what I need to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `MouseListener` to detect the double click, see [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) for more details.

With the `MouseEvent`, extract the `Point` which represents the point that was clicked.

Use [`JTable#columnAtPoint`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#columnAtPoint(java.awt.Point)) and [`JTable#rowAtPoint`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#rowAtPoint(java.awt.Point)) to retrieve the cells row/column indices

Use [`JTable#getValueAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getValueAt(int,%20int)) to retrieve the value and show it in your `JOptionPane`

Comment: I didn't think to use a MouseListener... I've been trying to make it work with setCellEditor, this should work better. Thanks

Comment: Depending on how you table is setup, you might not get a double click event, just beware of that ;)

Comment: Got it, I had to have the mouseListener on the JTable instead of rootPane, and had to use MouseEvent.getClickCount() to detect double clicks. Thanks!